# Leerzeichen vor Einheiten?

Tags: punctuation

Werden Mengen und Einheiten im Deutschen durch ein Leerzeichen getrennt?

> 12 m/s
>
> 1Å

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Ja: laut DIN 1301 (Teil 2: „Einheitennamen, Einheitenzeichen“) werden Zahlenwert und Einheit im deutschen Sprachraum durch eine Leerstelle getrennt.

Die Gradzeichen (°, ′, ″ und ′′′) sind wichtige Ausnahmen. Hier wird *nur dann* ein Leerzeichen eingefügt, wenn ein Einheitszeichen folgt (*9°2'*, jedoch *7␣°C* – die Einheit ist hier *°C*).

Einheitsnamen (wie „Liter“) werden grundsätzlich getrennt.

Beispiele:

> 180°
>   24 °C
>   1,00 €
>   12 m/s²
>   220 VA
>   7°21'29"

Quelle: [Der korrekte Umgang mit Größen, Einheiten und Gleichungen (pdf)](https://karriere.rohde-schwarz.de/fileadmin/customer/downloads/PDF/Der_korrekte_Umgang_mit_Groessen_Einheiten_und_Gleichungen_bro_de_01.pdf).

<sub>Außerdem wird empfohlen, bei elektronischem Satz ein geschütztes Leerzeichen zu verwenden (also eines, das nicht umgebrochen werden darf). Aus stilistischen Gründen wird oft ein schmales Leerzeichen benutzt.</sub>

Comment: Wäre fantastisch wenn jemand die Situation in Österreich und der Schweiz [ergänzen](http://german.stackexchange.com/posts/322/edit) könnte.

Comment: Ich bin mir ziemlich sicher, dass es in A un CH genauso ist.

Comment: Übrigens, typographisch korrekt ist ein schmales Leerzeichen, also z.B. in TeX $1\,m$.

Comment: @FUZxxl Wollte ich auch gerade sagen.

Comment: @FUZxxl Das Einheitenzeichen ist allerdings *nie* kursiv. Also z. B. (mehrteilige Abkürzungen übrigens auch mit Leerraum) in Tex: `$1\,\text{m}$` – oder halt gleich `siunitx`.

Comment: Es gibt übrigens auch schmale geschützte Leerzeichen. Das vereint also den Abstand mit dem Schutz, dass es nicht umgebrochen wird, siehe [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gesch%C3%BCtztes_Leerzeichen#Schmales_gesch%C3%BCtztes_Leerzeichen)